# Widgets are not updating post-boot on CyanogenMod nightlies

Tags: cyanogenmod, app-widgets

I am using the Moto G 4G (Peregrine, XT1039). Cyanogenmod 12.1 latest nightly. I update once a week. Widgets are not updating post-boot on CyanogenMod nightlies. Do you know why?

I have not deactivated background data and no battery saving plan is running. I can receive WhatsApp messages and emails but my homescreen widgets stay the way they were when I started the phone. So today it is still Thursday on my calendar widget.

Comment: You mean they are not retrieving data?  Does other background data work?  What device and OS version are you running?

Comment: Nightly builds are always considered unstable, there's a possibility that something is broken. Usually the best & easiest approach is to contact the developer, perhaps through their forum... though it's also ok to ask here. (but it will take more time since nobody is CM dev). Anyway, have you tried resetting the widget by removing and readding them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing TK-Gapps micro on top of the pico that were installed.

A day later it stopped working again. If I use the google now launcher instead of trebuchet it does work.